# How do I rectify this AWS EKS configuration error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Please I have created an eks cluster on amazon and I have been trying to configure the cluster on my terminal and I keep getting errors. Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing? All my credentials are correct but each time I run that command, the same error every time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKi8o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your error image indicated the cluster that you are looking for does not exist in the region. You can list all clusters in that region to check: `eksctl get clusters --region us-east-1`. You can also list all clusters across all regions: `eksctl get clusters --all-regions` to ensure your cluster does exist in the first place. More info about [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/introduction/) here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I was able to figure out what the problem was. I was working with a different account.